# Dump leak connections in WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10, connection-leaks, ironjacamar

I am trying to dump leaked connections managed by a MySQL Data Source in WildFly 10.1, but I am not able to find the leak file or the leak dump.

Why is the `leaks.txt` file not being generated? And also, where should I look for the file?

### Procedure

I registered the leak connection pool in the `standalone.bat` file:

```
"JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dironjacamar.mcp=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.LeakDumperManagedConnectionPool -Dironjacamar.leaklog=leaks.txt"
```

I can confirm that properties are being set in WildFly since shows in the log:

```
JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dironjacamar.mcp=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.LeakDumperManagedConnectionPool -Dironjacamar.leaklog=leaks.txt"
```

After it, I leak some connections in my mock application in order to generate data. Then I run the CLI command flushing all connections getting a positive response:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=mysql-ds:flush-all-connection-in-pool
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

But I can't find the `leaks.txt` file anywhere.

I am using [this article](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/wildfly9/detecting-connection-leaks-in-wildfly-9) and also [IronJacamar leak documentation](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/index.html#configuration_ironjacamar_leakpool) as reference.

> The leak detector pool is configured using the ironjacamar.mcp system
>   property with a value of
>
> `org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.LeakDumperManagedConnectionPool`
>
> This configuration applies to all connection pools used by IronJacamar.
>
> The system property ironjacamar.leaklog can be used to have the leaks
>   dumped out into a special file separate from the logging setup.
>
> An example
>
> `-Dironjacamar.mcp=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.LeakDumperManagedConnectionPool
>   -Dironjacamar.leaklog=leaks.txt`

### Updates

Thread [969369](https://developer.jboss.org/message/969369) created in JBoss forum so they can help with it as well.

Bug reported [JBJCA-1360](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBJCA-1360).

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path so you have control over where the file is created? Ex `-Dironjacamar.leaklog=/path/to/leaks.txt', adapt the path to your own environment and operating system.

Comment: @Gimby yes, also tried absolute path "d:/leaks.txt" but no file was generated, no error in the logs as well.

Comment: Check `<flush-strategy>AllConnections</flush-strategy>` in standalone.xml file to verify that your flush strategy is present.

Comment: @Maverick no, it is not present. Should it be?

Comment: we use domain mode and when I specified flush strategy from admin console then wildfly added it to my data source configuration in domain.xml file. Whatever you install wildfly will add a configuration in your standalone.xml file.

Comment: @Maverick can you list the steps you took in order to specify the flush strategy?

Comment: In domain mode, you can access configurations and datasources via UI [link](http://imgur.com/a/IjW9h).  I am not sure whether UI is available for standalone mode. One more thing, if you are using `<cached-connection-manager debug=”true”/>`
it will automatically close un-closed JCA connections and print a warning/stacktrace, showing exactly where the transaction was opened.  In that case, I am not sure ironjacamar will be able to catch any exception.

Comment: @Maverick I found the configuration, but applying `<flush-strategy>AllConnections</flush-strategy>` didn't change the behavior of IronJacamar. The leak file was not generated.

Comment: @Maverick `<cached-connection-manager debug=”true”/>` is already set as well.

Comment: you can also post your question in wildfly forums https://developer.jboss.org/en/wildfly/content . Most of the developers working on wildfly reply to posts.

Comment: Did you try after changing `<cached-connection-manager debug=”true”/>` to `<cached-connection-manager />`

Comment: @Maverick yes, it dumps some information on the server log, but still the IronJacamar TXT file is not generated.

Comment: I am not sure that I can help you more.  I will strongly suggest to post your question in wildfly forum. Wildfly developers monitor all posts and reply everyday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136995/discussion-between-maverick-and-bonanzaone).

Answer (score 1):

Thread [969369](https://developer.jboss.org/message/969369) created in JBoss forum so they can help with it as well.

### Workaround

There is an alternative approach to log leak connections, however I think it shouldn't apply as a final answer to this question.

The workaround for this is enabling `debug` and `error` modes to **true** for JCA Subsystem (It seems that restarting the server is not needed).

```
/subsystem=jca/cached-connection-manager=cached-connection-manager:write-attribute(name=debug, value=true)
/subsystem=jca/cached-connection-manager=cached-connection-manager:write-attribute(name=error, value=true)
```

You can check the logs as the server will dump exceptions pointing out the stacktrace that helps you find the leaks. It is not as clean, but it helped us find where the problem was in our code.

Comment: I found why `leaks.txt` does not appear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106612/1189424. You can add `mcp` option of your datatasource, and flush connections.